# "Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'" when running "ng serve" on my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to run my app and i get this error. I tried some solution I've found on internet,like uninstalling angular/cli,reinstalling it,checking if in my package.json the version was correct,if it was `@angular/cli` either than `@angular-cli` in devDependencies and some other stuff,like uninstalling and installing npm,deleting node modules and reinstalling it,but none of the previous solved my problem...
this is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "techlog-admin",
  "version": "3.2.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "IE 11"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint techlog-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.11",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "3.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "3.4.2",
    "@nebular/bootstrap": "3.4.2",
    "@nebular/moment": "^3.4.0",
    "@nebular/security": "3.4.2",
    "@nebular/theme": "3.4.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "7.2.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.4.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "ckeditor": "4.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "echarts": "^4.0.2",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "leaflet": "1.2.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "2.0.8",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.3.5",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-show-hide-password": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.1.4",
    "ngx-typeahead": "^6.2.0",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "or": "^0.2.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.11",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.10",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.3",
    "@types/node": "6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  }
}
```

If you need any more information ask me and I'll post as soon as I can! Thank you

Comment: Keep it in sync with project's `@angular/cli` version

Answer (score 2):

Few thing to try with this error

You can use these command to see if it work.

```
npm uninstall angular-cli -g
npm uninstall angular-cli --save
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli --save
npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the things I've found in other Stackoverflow and github threads, but the only things that worked for me was to downgraded the angular@cli to 7.2 (which is the current angular packages version in my project) and also install manually the following packages:

> npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save
>
> npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular

My package.json contains both of these dependencies, however it seemed that npm install couldn't install them. So I had to do it manually.

For what I understand, this is an issue between newer and older versions of the angular/cli.

Hope I could help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't see much of a point. If angular/cli suffers from retro-compatibility issues, I'd rather install things only inside my projects dependencies. In an extreme case, I would create a VM or a container to handle different projects. Lol

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few months back. I tried the following steps and I was able to compile the code without any more issues:

- You could create an empty angular project and compare their `package.json` and manually edit the angular dependencies.
- Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- Run `npm i --save`